# how get access to children in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i am using jquery in my code and i have a list and when i call my function to access text element in my code undefined is back.

this is my code

```js
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var place_obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    for (var k = 0; k < Object.keys(place_obj).length; k++) {
      if (k % 2 == 0) {
        document.getElementById('dropdownplace').innerHTML +=
          '<a class="dropdown-item font_size_x1" style="background-color:#d9d9d947" ' +
          'href="#" onclick="pFilter()" id="' + k + '"><span class="">- </span>' + place_obj[k].Type + '</a>';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('dropdownplace').innerHTML +=
          '<a class="dropdown-item font_size_x1" ' +
          'href="#" onclick="pFilter()" id="' + k + '"><span>- </span>' + place_obj[k].Type + '</a>';
      }
    }
  }
};

function pFilter() {
  var place = document.getElementById('1').value;
  console.log(place) //undefiend 
}
```

Comment: There's no jQuery in that code...?

Comment: Can we please see some HTML? It's not obvious what element would have `id="1"` from your code.

Comment: None `form` elements, like your `a`, doesn't have a `.value` property. Use `.innerText` or `.textContent`, e.g. `document.getElementById('1').innerText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to select clicked element text . You don't need `id` basically, you can call current clicked element by `event.target` . I created mock json instead of xmlhttp response ....

```js
var place_obj = [{Type: 'a'},{Type: 'b'}];
    for (var k = 0; k < Object.keys(place_obj).length; k++) {
      if (k % 2 == 0) {
        document.getElementById('dropdownplace').innerHTML +=
          '<a class="dropdown-item font_size_x1" style="background-color:#d9d9d947" ' +
          'href="#" onclick="pFilter()"><span class="">- </span>' + place_obj[k].Type + '</a>';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('dropdownplace').innerHTML +=
          '<a class="dropdown-item font_size_x1" ' +
          'href="#" onclick="pFilter()"><span>- </span>' + place_obj[k].Type + '</a>';
      }
    }

function pFilter() {
  console.log(event.target.textContent);
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdownplace">
</div>
```